# Matrix representation of the derivative operator

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, change-of-basis

It is the first time that I do one of these exercises and I would like to know if what I have done is correct. The exercise is as follows:

> Let $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of polynomials with degree at most $4$ and let $D:P_4(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_4(\mathbb{R})$ the derivative operator. Find $[D]_B$ and $[D]_{B'}$ for $B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ and $B'=\{1,x,2x^2,3x^3,4x^4\}$. Also, find the matrix of change of basis from $B$ to $B'$ of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$.

My attempt: $$[D]_B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0\\
 0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&3&0\\
0&0&0&0&4\\
0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

In this case I'm not too sure, but this is what I did

$$[D]_{B'}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0\\
 0&0&4&0&0\\
0&0&0&9/2&0\\
0&0&0&0&16/3\\
0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

For the matrix of change of basis, we have that \begin{eqnarray*}1&=&1\cdot1+0\cdot x +0\cdot 2x^2+0\cdot 3x^3+0\cdot 4x^4\\
x&=&0\cdot1+1\cdot x +0\cdot 2x^2+0\cdot 3x^3+0\cdot 4x^4\\
x^2&=&0\cdot1+0\cdot x +1/2\cdot 2x^2+0\cdot 3x^3+0\cdot 4x^4\\
x^3&=&0\cdot1+0\cdot x +0\cdot 2x^2+1/3\cdot 3x^3+0\cdot 4x^4\\
x^4&=&0\cdot1+0\cdot x +0\cdot 2x^2+0\cdot 3x^3+1/4\cdot 4x^4 \end{eqnarray*}

Thus, this matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0\\
 0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1/2&0&0\\
0&0&0&1/3&0\\
0&0&0&0&1/4\end{pmatrix}$$

Am I right?

Comment: Seems sensible to me, both conceptually and from a few simple examples